# assign multiple color to each vertex in igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I have a dataframe `d`:

```
d<-structure(list(V1 = c(1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 9L, 7L), V2 = c(2L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 3L, 1L, 8L, 5L)), 
.Names = c("V1", "V2"), class ="data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))

g<-graph.data.frame(d,directed = F)
```

I would assign to each vertex one or more colors depending on its affiliation variable given in a dataframe `m`

```
m<-structure(list(vertex = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 6L), affilation = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L)), 
.Names = c("vertex", "affilation"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))
```

i would to ask if there is a simple method in igraph package to assign one or multiple color to each vertex according to its affiliation

Comment: And what exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(EDIT) Because the edges were specified as integers the vertices were not in order in the graph. I changed the initial graph.data.frame call to specify the order, then everything should work.

```
g<-graph.data.frame(d,directed = F, vertices = 1:10)
```

You can assign color as a vertex attribute by assigning into V(g)$color. Here's some code for your example (only for a single affiliation)

```
# Put in vertex order
m <- m[order(m$vertex), ]

# Create a palette (any palette would do)
pal <- rainbow(n=length(unique(m$affilation)))

# Get each node's first affiliation
oneAffil <- m$affilation[!duplicated(m$vertex)]

# Assign to the vertices as a color attribute
V(g)$color <- pal[oneAffil]

plot(g)
```

[image]

Now for multiple affiliations it's not too clear what you want. You could look at `vertex.shape.pie` that can draw shapes with more than one color on. Something like this works for me (but there's quite a bit of data wrangling to get it going)

```
# Use a cast to split out affiliation in each group as a column
library(reshape2)
am <- acast(m, formula = vertex ~ affilation)

# Turn this into a list
values <- lapply(seq_len(nrow(am)), function(i) am[i,])


plot(g, vertex.shape="pie", vertex.pie=values, vertex.pie.color=list(pal))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks but it didn't give me the correct color for each vertex for example, the  vertex 10 has affiliation 3 but it is colored with three color. i wonder if there is a simple way to color each vertex according to its affiliation

Comment: Hi, sorry, I missed the notification. Yes, your totally right. Something went wrong with the indexing there. I'll patch it up when I get to a computer.

Comment: The reason for the problem is that I was using numerical order but the vertices were not in the graph in numerical order. I changed the initial graph call to `g<-graph.data.frame(d,directed = F, vertices = 1:10)` and this fixed it.